# Can't upgrade to 14.04 due to update-manager-kde being in the removal blacklist

Tags: upgrade

Trying to upgrade to new LTS

Get error `... cannot calculate upgrade...` and the upgrade stops.

In `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` :

```
 2014-08-22 03:42:25,357 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'update-manager-kde' is marked for removal but it is in the removal blacklist.'
```

Too scared to manually remove a package that is named **update-manager-kde**!

Comment: What version are you running currently? If it's old enough (11.04 and older, I think), then it is using a different package suite. The Kubuntu packaging suite in 11.10+ is Muon, which replaces whatever was before (can't remember).

Comment: *How* are you trying to upgrade? What method are you using?

Comment: Hello I currently run 12.04 (the previous LTS) and try to upgrade because the system invites me to do so. I always only upgrade from LTS to LTS and via the prompted pop-ups, not via terminal commands. Similar issues that I see on askubuntu or launchpad do not apply to me, because they either mention unity/ubuntu (I need Kubuntu with a K) and/or intermediate relases which are not LTS. Thanks!